# Load resources (Images) on more projects

Tags: delphi, resources, components, timagelist

I have a component. In the component, I need to load dynamic TImageList.

This way I use today, but in all my projects, I need to add all the image, one at a time.

```
function NavigatorImages: TImageList;
var
   vIcon: TBitmap;
   I: Integer;
begin
   if FNavigatorImages = nil then
   begin
      vIcon := TBitmap.Create;
      try
         FNavigatorImages := TImageList.Create (nil);
         FNavigatorImages.Height := 16;
         FNavigatorImages.Width := 16;
         for I := 0 to 11 do
         begin
            vIcon.LoadFromResourceName (HInstance, 'IMAGE_' + IntToStr(I));
            FNavigatorImages.AddMasked (vIcon, vIcon.Canvas.Pixels[0,        FNavigatorImages.Height - 1]);
         end;
      finally
         vIcon.Free;
      end;
   end;
   Result := FNavigatorImages;
end;
```

How do I create a single resource file, Which for example, contains multiple images can be loaded into the component without adding resources in each project. You have some way?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to add it to every project you want to use it, but there are ways to make the task easier.

1. Create the `.res` file using a `.rc` file and the `brcc` tool:

   ```
   brcc32 -fo output.res input.rc
   ```
2. Add the same `.res` file to every project you want to use those images (Project >> Add to Project or just edit `.dpr` to add `{R 'path/filename.res'}`. If you have a common unit to all these projects (which is the case if that component you talk about is a custom one), you could also add the `.res` file to that unit and the resources will be loaded to all of them.
3. It's also worth noting that if you add your resources specifying both the `.res` and the `.rc` (`{$R 'output.res' 'input.rc'}`), Delphi will compile your resource file automatically for you (I couldn't determine exactly when it decides to do that, but if you compile your projects a couple of times, the resources files will certainly get compiled too).

Sample `.rc` file:

```
IMAGE_1 BITMAP Path\Image1.bmp
```

The second parameter is the [Resource-Definition Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381043(v=vs.85).aspx).

Of course, if any of those images change, you'll have to recompile the `.rc` file manually.

Comment: Once you have the resource compiled and added to a project, `TImageList` has several methods for loading the resource - `GetResource()`, `GetInstRes()`, `ResourceLoad()`, and `ResInstLoad()`.